# Batch script to copy file

Tags: bash

How to create a batch file to copy a particular file from one folder to another. if the destination folder is not created, the script should create it and copy the files there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xcopy "c:\folder 1\file.txt" "c:\folder 2\"
```